# Can't run CGI script

Tags: cgi, raspberry-pi3, cgi-bin

I have a problem with my CGI script.
Here is what I do with my script :

- create `test.cgi` in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` > `chmod -x test.cgi`> `./test.cgi`
  It return an Internal Server error,
  [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzNJX.png)

I detetect that my system doesn't see where I created this script, so I :

- change `ScriptAlias` to `Alias` of `serve-cgi-bin.conf`
  Now, It can see the script, but I can't execute, I return the content of script, [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXLVc.png)

I do it on my raspberry. Does anyone see and can fix it?
Many thanks